# Preventing images from being downloaded when they are inside an in-memory element

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a situation where I need to take a large HTML string and wrap it inside a `div` (client-side). Then I feed this `div` to some DOM parser which turns it into a JSON document. This is a fairly simple task which is solvable by the following code:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = content; // where content is my HTML string
SomeDOMParser.parse(div); // getting the desired result
```

However, I noticed something very strange. When I set the in-memory div's inner HTML content the browser treats the images (I presume it also does it for iframes as-well) as if they are in DOM. What I mean is that it actually fetches the images!

Given I have the following HTML string:

```html
<p>
    Text <img src="foo.jpg">
    Text <img src="bar.jpg">
</p>
<figure>
    <img src="baz.jpg">
</figure>
```

When I wrap it in a div (`div.innerHTML = content`), the browser actually fetches `foo.jpg`, `bar.jpg` and `baz.jpg`! Even tho the images are at the moment only in memory!

I tried this in Chrome and Firefox and the results were the same. I've also tried maybe using `insertAdjacentHTML` hoping for a different result but the result was the same.

In my case, I could have an HTML string with over 100 images in it and all I need is to parse it into a JSON structure. I don't want the browser to fetch the images. It causes the page to load awfully slow. Is there any way I can stop the browser from downloading the images?

### Edit

It seems like that if I parse the string using the `DOMParser` it works without fetching the images:

```js
const htmlString = `<div>${content}</div>`;
const parser = new DOMParser;
const div = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html').body.firstChild;
SomeDOMParser.parse(div);
```

I'm still wondering if this is actually the best way to do it?

Comment: May be you need to use Node.textContent. This doesn't parse the passed content as HTML, but instead inserts it as raw text.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: @Omar but I need it to be parsed as an HTML. Basically it has to return a valid DOM where it can also be queried